# Implementing Squeeze and Excitation block with pretrained resnet

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to implement SE block with any pretrained resnet architecture.

```
self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet34(pretrained=pretrained)

self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
    self.encoder.conv1,
    self.encoder.bn1,
    self.encoder.relu
    SeBlock(64,2),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2) )

self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
    self.encoder.layer1,
    SeBlock(64,2),
    )

self.conv3 = nn.Sequential(
    self.encoder.layer2,
    SeBlock(128,2),
    )

self.conv4 = nn.Sequential(
    self.encoder.layer3,
    SeBlock(256,2),
    )

self.conv5 = nn.Sequential(
    self.encoder.layer4,
    SeBlock(512,2),
    )
```

Above is my code but It is not working out. Looking into githubs they build resnet from scratch and induce SE block and then load model.state_dict() weights for the layers of resnet and train the remaining model.
I just need to know what is the correct procedure to use SE block with pretrained resnet.?

Thanks.!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PyTorch much, but you can implement the same using TensorFlow-keras. It is pretty straightforward.
Firstly, load the pre-trained model from keras.applications with your desired input size, eg.  `keras.applications.VGG19(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = (50, 50, 3)).`
Then, selectly load the trained layer from the model load before. Apply SENET attention in between the layers as you desire.
Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Conv2D, Input, BatchNormalization, Reshape, GlobalAveragePooling2D, AveragePooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D, Flatten , ReLU, Layer, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.activations import sigmoid, softmax, relu, tanh
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential

class SENET_Attn(Layer):
    """
    Channel Attention Block as reported in SENET
    """
    def __init__(self,out_dim, ratio, layer_name="SENET"):
        super(SENET_Attn, self).__init__()
        self.out_dim = out_dim
        self.ratio = ratio
        self.layer_name = layer_name
            
    def build(self, ratio, layer_name="SENET"):
        self.Global_Average_Pooling = GlobalAveragePooling2D(keepdims= True)
        self.Fully_connected_1_1 = Dense(units= self.out_dim/self.ratio, name=self.layer_name+'_fully_connected1',
                                kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform")
        self.Relu = ReLU()
        self.Fully_connected_2 = Dense(units=self.out_dim, name=layer_name+'_fully_connected2', activation = "tanh")
        self.Sigmoid = Activation("sigmoid")
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs = tf.cast(inputs, dtype = "float32")
        squeeze = self.Global_Average_Pooling(inputs)
        excitation = self.Fully_connected_1_1(squeeze)
        excitation = self.Relu(excitation)
        excitation = self.Fully_connected_2(excitation)
        excitation =  self.Sigmoid(excitation)
        excitation = tf.reshape(excitation, [-1,1,1,self.out_dim])
        
        scale = inputs * excitation
        return scale
Vgg = VGG19(include_top = False,input_shape = (50,50,3))

# SENET-Attn VGG19
ratio =16

input_layer = Input(shape=(50,50,3))
out = Vgg.layers[1](input_layer) # Block one of VGG19
out = Vgg.layers[2](out)
out = Vgg.layers[3](out)

out = Vgg.layers[4](out) # Block two of VGG19
out = Vgg.layers[5](out)
out = Vgg.layers[6](out)

#out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[7](out) # Block three of VGG19
out = Vgg.layers[8](out)
out = Vgg.layers[9](out)
out = Vgg.layers[10](out)
out = Vgg.layers[11](out)
 
out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[12](out) # Block four of VGG19
out = Vgg.layers[13](out)
out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[14](out)
out = Vgg.layers[15](out)
out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[16](out)

out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[17](out) #Block five of VGG19

out = Vgg.layers[18](out)
out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[19](out)
out = Vgg.layers[20](out)
out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[21](out)

out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
flatten = Flatten()(out)
out = Dense(100)(flatten)
out = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(out)
out = Dense(100)(out)
out = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(out)
out = Dense(2)(out)
out = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(out)

model = Model(input_layer, out)
model.compile(optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss= tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
              , metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```